# Which KeyEvent to use to navigate to next text field in Chrome browser on an Android device

Tags: java, android, browser, keyevent

I am working on a custom keyboard for an Android device and I am looking for a KeyEvent to navigate from one input field to another.

I already tried some of them (KeyEvent.NAVIGATE_NEXT, ...), but none of them worked. The following one will switch to the URL bar:

```
getCurrentInputConnection().sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_TAB));
```

I need this for testing the keyboard. So if someone knows the key event or if someone knows any other way to navigate to the next input field, please let me know!